# MassTransit ConfigureBatchPublish - sending duplicate batchesa

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, .net-6.0, masstransit

I have trouble understanding what is `ConfigureBatchPublish` actually doing.

The way I've tried to work with it is having this configuration on the mass transit buss:

```
h.ConfigureBatchPublish(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Enabled = true;
    cfg.MessageLimit = 100;
    cfg.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
    cfg.SizeLimit = 1024;
});
```

And then I've tried with both the `IPublishEndpoint` and `ISendEndpoint` to send/publish a couple of messages, around 1000. I was sending them 1 by 1, no `Task.WhenAll` involved. By description, which is:

> MassTransit will briefly buffer messages before sending them to RabbitMQ, to increase message throughput. While use of the default values is recommended, the batch options can be configured.

I am expecting that instead of publishing them 1 by 1, mass transit will try to wait either until a batch of 100 is filled or if 100 milliseconds have passed. But what I am seeing is that messages are sent 1 by 1 even with this config applied and also, I am now waiting 100 milliseconds for each call on the Send method.

Also, even weirder is that I have tried combining that settings with the `SendBatch` method on the `ISendEndpoint`. I split the 1000 records in batches of 100, and I decided to use `SendBatch` on them. `MassTransit` was now caching each 100 records, and re-sending it on the next `SendBatch` call. Went something like this:

- first batch - 100 records;
- second batch - 200 records (100 new records and the 100 cached records);
- third batch - 300 records (100 new records and the 200 cached records);
- so on and so fort;

How does this even make sense?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're sending multiple messages, you should *not* `await` each call to `Send`.
2. Your batch publish timeout is *way too high*. I've never set it higher than 3-4 milliseconds. There is no point, it's *only* for high latency to the broker scenarios.
3. Your size limit is *way too low*. It should be the default value unless you have a specific reason to change it (you probably don't).

TL;DR - you're overthinking it. Enable it with the default settings, don't await each call to send/publish.

Comment: Hey Chris, thank you for the answer. So, the settings that I had there were specifically configured like that to slow down the process so that I could observe it.

I still don't understand how the batch work, because at the end of the day, even if I am not awaiting it, it doesn't seem like its creating any batch behind the scenes. Even with the default settings.